# How can i make it display 5 different asterisk using functions

Tags: c++

I need to make a program to that display five different asterisk using functions C++ for a test and currently, its saying too many arguments and also cant take one arguments

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void asterisk();

int main()
{
    int k;
    int i;
    // Asking the user to input 5 random between 1 to 30
    cout << "Enter 5 numbers between 1 to 30" << endl;
    cin >> k;

    asterisk(i);

    return 0;
}

void display(int a)
{

    // Using for loop to get the asterisk and print it out to the console
    // How many numbers its looking for the program

    for (int i = 1; i <= +a; ++i) // How many asterisk is getting printing out at a time
        cout << '*'; // asterisk
    cout << '\n'; // new line
}
```

Comment: You ask the user to enter 5 numbers then read only 1. Then call a function `void asterisk()` that you declared to have no parameters but pass 1 parameter `i` that was never initialized.

Comment: stackoverflow change the formatting btw

Comment: The easy way to format is the console.log example here: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) that way you don't need to modify your code at all just copy and paste and put ``` on a line before and ``` on a line after your code.

Comment: Can't be done. There is only one asterisk: `*`. The other 4 must be imposters.

Comment: I fixed the code format.

Comment: The [`std::string` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) has a constructor that [creates a string of N counts of a character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).  You could cheat and create a string with asterisks and then print it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have not understood wrong you are looking something like this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
void display(int a);
vector<uint> asterisks = vector<uint>(5);


int main()
{

    // Asking the user to input 5 random between 1 to 30
    cout << "Enter "<<asterisks.size()<<" numbers between 1 to 30" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<asterisks.size();i++) {
        cout << i << ":\t";
        cin >> asterisks[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<asterisks.size();i++)
    display(asterisks[i]);

    return 0;

}

void display(int a) {
for (int i = 1; i <= +a; ++i) cout << '*'; // asterisk
    cout << '\n'; // new line
}
```

Now you store what the user chooses in a vector and then print the content of the vector using the display function
Hope it will be helpful

Comment: You don't really need a vector here, just get one number at a time and call `display` with it immediately.

Comment: I thought that he first want to ask number and then want to print asterisk, if is so you need vector

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear but if you are looking for a program ask a user **how many stars he/she wants from 1 to 30, and instead of the number replaced with '*'**, you should do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string display(int numberOf)
{
    string outPut = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOf; i++)
    {
        outPut += "*";
    }

    return outPut;
}

int main()
{

    int numberOfStar;
    cout << "Enter number of star between 1 to 30: ";
    cin >> numberOfStar;

    if (numberOfStar >=1 && numberOfStar <= 30)
    {
        cout << "You have entered " << numberOfStar << " star(s)" << endl;
        string result = display(numberOfStar);
        cout << "\nThe output is: \n" << result;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You have entered a number which is out of range (1 to 30)";
    }


}
```